# violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to run a code that sends a search term to google and record google suggestions.

```
import requests
import re
import time
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from param_config import config
import cPickle

START_SPELL_CHECK="<span class=\"spell\">Showing results for</span>"
END_SPELL_CHECK="<br><span class=\"spell_orig\">Search instead for"

HTML_Codes = (
        ("'", '&#39;'),
        ('"', '&quot;'),
        ('>', '&gt;'),
        ('<', '&lt;'),
        ('&', '&amp;'),
)

def spell_check(s):
    q = '+'.join(s.split())
    time.sleep(  randint(0,2) ) #relax and don't let google be angry
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="+q)
    content = r.text
    start=content.find(START_SPELL_CHECK) 
    if ( start > -1 ):
        start = start + len(START_SPELL_CHECK)
        end=content.find(END_SPELL_CHECK)
        search= content[start:end]
        search = re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', search)
        for code in HTML_Codes:
            search = search.replace(code[1], code[0])
        search = search[1:]
    else:
        search = s
    return search ;

searches = [ "metal plate cover gcfi", 'artric air portable", "roll roofing lap cemet", "basemetnt window", "vynal grip strip", "lawn mower- electic" ]
speel_check_search=[]
for i,search in enumerate(searches):
    speel_check_search.append(spell_check(str(search)))
```

The code runs fine for some time but with  Large searches list the code runs for a while then terminates with the following error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: Uhh, bad error. I had something similar in Python ftp, adding the right ssl version (`ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` or similar) fixed it.

Comment: Do you have openssl installed? Also why are you trying to parse html using str methods?